# Is it possible to insert a batch of messages in Artemis JMS

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I am working on a Java application which receives a list of messages and then inserts them in a queue. Is it possible to directly insert a list of messages in my Artemis JMS server (a kind of batch insert)? Or must I insert them one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the JMS API you can create a "transacted" session, send a batch of messages, and then call `commit()` on the session. From the point of view of the application it seems like messages are being sent one-by-one since `send()` is called for every message. However, the most time consuming work only happens when `commit()` is called which only happens once per batch. This is often done as a performance optimization especially for **persistent** messages to avoid the repeated blocking that happens on individual, non-transacted sends. Using transactions for batching purposes is discussed in the "Tuning JMS" section of the [ActiveMQ Artemis performance tuning documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/perf-tuning.html).